# How can I get different item position with same classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When mousemove() it only gets the position of first item. Now they are all overlapping. How can I improve this?

https://codepen.io/penny289/pen/JjJzYbv

```js
$(window).mousemove(function(evt){
  $('.img-box').each(function(){
    var positionX= $(this).offset().left/100
    var positionY= $(this).offset().top/100

    $(this).css("left",positionX+evt.pageX/100+"%")
    .css("top",positionY+evt.pageY/100+"%")
  })
    
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-box box-1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632012643163-c9c4fbbd9f05?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzEwNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632778931175-128809d8facc?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzE2MQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594734044877-2ebba0c14720?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzIwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-4">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630231211819-a131d7538a41?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzIxNQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-5">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632073591482-0d69552e07df?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzI1NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think you only get the first item? When I run the codepen i can see that all img-box is getting triggered.

Comment: Plesae post the [mcve] here

Comment: I assume that you want to keep the images next to each other based on their original position, but you are dividing by 100, so any relative position they had to each other just is reduced to nothing in 1 or 2 event handler invocations. Using `console.log` you can see that `this` *is* what you expect it to be though

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I want these item not overlapping. It seems that they all share the same position info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not get the coordinates of the first image only. Rather, you seem to have several problems:

- You are dividing by 100, presumably because you are working with percentages, but unless your screen is 100 pixels wide that is obviously wrong.
- .offset() does return an offset relative to the document, but you are positioning your items relative to your container
- You are trying to dynamically grab the offset every time, but if you go for this approach you would need to know what part of that offset is from the previous time you called this function. Otherwise you start accumulating the x and y position of your MouseEvent and quickly move the entire thing off the screen.

There is no reason for you to use percentages, so just work with absolute pixels and simplify your code.

Then store the initial offset with `.data(..)` so you don't have to subtract your previous mouse position and keep track of that every single time. Since you want to have the offset relative to the container (because your css renders it relative to the container), subtract the container offset from your image offset.

Now you can make the images move with your mouse by adding your mouse pageX/pageY.

Besides that, you should use a debounce (does not work in stacksnippets) and `window.requestAnimationFrame` so your cpu does not melt trying to draw something for every pixel your mouse moves, but rather only when it is ready to draw a single frame.

```js
$(window).mousemove(function(evt){
  //_.debounce(() => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      const containerOffsetX = $('.container').offset().left;
      const containerOffsetY = $('.container').offset().top;

      $('.img-box').each(function(elem, i){
        let imageOffsetX = $(this).data('offsetX');
        if (!imageOffsetX) {
          imageOffsetX = $(this).offset().left - containerOffsetX;
          $(this).data('offsetX', imageOffsetX);
        }
        let imageOffsetY = $(this).data('offsetY');
        if (!imageOffsetY) {
          imageOffsetY = $(this).offset().top - containerOffsetY;
          $(this).data('offsetY', imageOffsetY);
        }
      
        const mouseOffsetX = evt.pageX;
        const mouseOffsetY = evt.pageY;
      
        const newPositionX = imageOffsetX + mouseOffsetX;
        const newPositionY = imageOffsetY + mouseOffsetY;
  
        $(this).css("left", `${newPositionX}px`)
        .css("top", `${newPositionY}px`)
      });
    });
  //}, 10);
});
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.container{
  width:70vw;
  height:500px;
  position:relative;
}

.img-box{
  position:absolute;
}

.img-box img{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  /* transform:translate(-50%); */
}

.img-box.box-1{
  top:10%;
}

.img-box.box-2{
  left:20%;
  top:80%;
}

.img-box.box-3{
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}

.img-box.box-4{
  top:10%;
  left:90%
}

.img-box.box-5{
  left:90%;
  top:70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-box box-1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632012643163-c9c4fbbd9f05?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzEwNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632778931175-128809d8facc?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzE2MQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594734044877-2ebba0c14720?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzIwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-4">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630231211819-a131d7538a41?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzIxNQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
  <div class="img-box box-5">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632073591482-0d69552e07df?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzMjk4MzI1NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85">
  </div>
</div>
```